# What is the best professional certificate for Digital Transformation?

Tags: professionalism, certification

First of all, I searched for the right site to ask this question and ended up with this site. So, if you think there is a better site to post this question please let me know.

I have been asked by my boss to get a professional certificate for Digital Transformation and I spent a quite time looking for such a certificate and the only one I found is "Certified Digital Transformation Professional (CDTP)". Are there alternatives to this certificate? If so, can you please suggest one?

Comment: This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - _why_ does your boss want you to get this certificate? In many ways, something like an AWS Solutions Architect is all about "digital transformation" but that may or may not be what your boss wants.

Answer (score 5):

"Digital Transformation" is absurdly, almost obscenely, under defined. It can mean anything from a website to a complete sales and support system to redesigning the company's internal process.

Get a specific description of what the boss wants you to work on, then find education which addresses those topics. If the boss can't explain it, ask them what they are hoping to achieve. If they can't answer that, they're suffering from an attack of buzzwords, and if you can't help them fix that you're on your own.

Comment: Although if their boss is just after buzzwords, the certificate linked by the OP seems ideal!

Comment: That kind of course might be of more use to the boss. "Here's what the term might mean and some of the things you can do. Now hire one of our consultants or take twelve more courses if you want to actually accomplish anything."